# Using all CPU cores with ABAQUS python script

Tags: abaqus

I try to submit a bunch of ABAQUS jobs through the following python code:

```
for i in range(n):
  mdb.jobs['job_'+str(i)].submit()
```

after that it follows another loop, which checks if each job has been completed:

```
for i in range(n):
  mdb.jobs['job_'+str(i)].waitForCompletion()
```

Unfortunately I get an error for at least one of the jobs, if n > 5. The error occurs is:

"XML parsing failure for job job_*i*.  Shutting down socket and terminating all further messages.  Please check the .log, .dat, .sta, or .msg files for information about the status of the job."

The script has been started within the ABAQUS GUI > Run Script. Does anyone know why this occurs and does there exist an python solution to distribute the jobs over all my available CPU cores?

Best regards and thanks!

Comment: is the error thrown by the submit or the waitforcompletion?

Answer (score 0):

Use both statements in the same loop:

```
for i in range(n):
    mdb.jobs['job_'+str(i)].submit()
    mdb.jobs['job_'+str(i)].waitForCompletion()
```